# Number of data files in tempdb in Availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups

We have configured AlwaysOn Availability Group with 3 node in Sync mode. The primary server got 16 core while the replicas have 10 core each. We have tempdb contention issue, just wondering if we can have different number of tempdb data files on nodes in Availability Group or do we have to have same number on each node. It is SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is it a TempDb _contention_ issue or a TempDb _performance_ issue?  It would be surprising to have a TempDb contention issue on SQL 2016 with 10 TempDb files.

Comment: No we have not got 10 tempdb files but 4 on each replica, was planning to increase it to 8 on each. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is not a problem with having different numbers of tempdb files on each machine,  you just need to be aware that should you failover to one of the machines with fewer files that you will run into the contention problem that you worked to alleviate on the new server.